# jQuery suggest list of autocomplete not showing up

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I change the autocomplete data source to my php file, and I have tried the code below. But it's not work, could someone suggest how to fix it?

Thanks

```
$('#search').autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/property_bldg.php",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                query: request.term
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                response( $.map( data.suggestions, function( item ) {
                    return {
                        label: item.text,
                        value: item.text
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1
})
```

Return

```
{query:'A',par1:'',suggestions:['AUSTIN RD','ARCH','ARGYLE ST','AMOY GDN','ARIA','AQUAMARINE','ACADEMIC TERR','APEX','ALLWAY GDN','AP LEI CHAU DRIVE'],data:[]}
```

Updated:

```
$('#autocomplete_propSearch').autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/property_bldg.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                query: request.term
            },
            complete: function (xhr, status) {
                if (status === 'error' || !xhr.responseText) {
                    alert('Error')
                }
                else {

                    response( $.map( xhr.responseText.suggestions, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item,
                            value: item
                        }
                    }));
                }
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1
})
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting in firebug or javascript console

Comment: @Satya no error, so I don't know what wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're iterating over an array of strings, but trying to access the `text` property of them. Change your map body to:

```
                return {
                    label: item,
                    value: item
                }
```

Working example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/D7cyH/). If that doesn't work for you, check whether the ajax call really completed successfully (by printing `data` to console, for instance).

**Update:** if your server is returning exactly what you posted, then it's not a valid **JSONP** response. See [this tutorial](http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/) and the jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for the proper way of doing JSONP (though, if you're querying the same domain that served the page, it's simpler - and safer - to use `json` instead).

For instance, if your server is receiving the query:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/property_bldg.php?callback=jQuery161006659467399874042_13‌​59964924178&query=a&_=1359964930143
```

The correct response should be:

```
jQuery161006659467399874042_13‌​59964924178({query:'A',par1:'',suggestions:['AUSTIN RD','ARCH','ARGYLE ST','AMOY GDN','ARIA','AQUAMARINE','ACADEMIC TERR','APEX','ALLWAY GDN','AP LEI CHAU DRIVE'],data:[]});
```

And its `content-type` should be `text/javascript` (not `application/json`). You can customize that if you want, read the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more info.

Comment: @CharlesYeung the autocomplete part is ok, as the example I posted shows. If that does not solve it, the problem must be in the ajax part. Call `console.log(data)` in the beginning of `success` to confirm it actually worked (and the data is really what you expect).

Comment: Yes, I have tried console.log(date) but nothing show on debug console. I am using localhost, is it the problem caused?

Comment: @CharlesYeung I see you're using `jsonp` (not `json`), is your server returning that data wrapped in the `jsonpCallback`? In other words, when jQuery sends `?callback=foo` does your server responds with `foo({ ... })`, or just `{ ... }`? Note that if you don't specify a custom name, jQuery will create a random one for you.

Comment: Also I found that the content-type of HTTP response header is `text/html`, is  there any problem?

Comment: @CharlesYeung I think by specifying `dataType` jQuery will disregard the content-type, but I'm not sure. But anyway, see my comment above about JSONP. If your page is being served by the same domain that you want to query, it's preferrable to use JSON instead.

Comment: The query show at debug console: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/property_bldg.php?callback=jQuery161006659467399874042_1359964924178&query=a&_=1359964930143` and the return: `{query:'A',par1:'',suggestions:['AUSTIN RD','ARCH','ARGYLE ST','AMOY GDN','ARIA','AQUAMARINE','ACADEMIC TERR','APEX','ALLWAY GDN','AP LEI CHAU DRIVE'],data:[]} `

Comment: Finally, I changed `success` to `complete` and it's work, please check my question again, but another problem is the response data is json formatted string, I tried to use `$.parseJSON` with `{query:'A',par1:'',suggestions:['AUSTIN RD','ARCH','ARGYLE ST','AMOY GDN','ARIA','AQUAMARINE','ACADEMIC TERR','APEX','ALLWAY GDN','AP LEI CHAU DRIVE'],data:[]}`, but not work.

Comment: Problem solved, because the json formatted string is invalid, it should be `"query":"A"xxx` instead of `query:'A'xxx`.